# Laravel manually calling sendResetLink() not working with localhost setup

Tags: laravel

I want to create a user from the command line and would like to set a random password and force the user to click a password reset link.

[Sending a password reset link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords#password-reset-link-handling-the-form-submission) is quite easy:

```php
$status = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $user->email]);
```

The issue is, that the password reset url in the email points to:

```
http://localhost/reset-password/...
```

Rather than:

```
http://localhost:8000/reset-password/...
```

I read that I need to [set the APP_URL to the correct localhost and port](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/password-reset-link-not-working-1):

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Now it all works fine - so why am I asking? When I use fortify and jetstream, this just works out of the box, with no port in the `APP_URL`. So why is it required here? What does fortify or jetstream different? Is my method the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related directly to Trusted Hosts section of Laravel documentation.

Laravel behaves differently based on .env file, that because we use local,test, and production enviroments.

Laravel as a server side software do not know about the origin of the request.

By default, Laravel will respond to all requests it receives regardless of the content of the HTTP request's Host header. This is the reason why we need to setup [Trusted Hosts](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#configuring-trusted-hosts).

From Laravel Documentation

If you look and dig into [this middleware](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustHosts.php) , you will find the response to your question. I think it has nothing to do with Fortify or Jetstream